# How can I call an on page PHP function by pressing a button?

Tags: javascript, php, minecraft

```
<?php
// Edit this ->
define( 'MQ_SERVER_ADDR', 'XX.XXX.XXX.XXX' );
define( 'MQ_SERVER_PORT', 25565 );
define( 'MQ_TIMEOUT', 1 );
// Edit this <-

// Display everything in browser, because some people can't look in logs for errors
Error_Reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
Ini_Set( 'display_errors', true );

require __DIR__ . '/status/MinecraftQuery.class.php';

$Timer = MicroTime( true );

$Query = new MinecraftQuery( );

try
{
    $Query->Connect( MQ_SERVER_ADDR, MQ_SERVER_PORT, MQ_TIMEOUT );
}
catch( MinecraftQueryException $e )
{
    $Exception = $e;
}

$Timer = Number_Format( MicroTime( true ) - $Timer, 4, '.', '' );
?>

<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<div class="spanx"><p>
<h1>Login</h1>
    Username:<br />
    <input type="text" name="username" style="height: 30px; style="width: 220px; value="" />
    <br/>
 <button>Submit</button>
<?php    // Example from PHP.net
    $string = '<?php if( ( $Players = $Query->GetPlayers( ) ) !== false ): ?>
<?php foreach( $Players as $Player ): ?>';
  if(stristr($string, 'Thisshouldbethestringfromthetextbox') === FALSE) {
    echo 'Player is not online';
  }
 ?>
```

Is my code. Basically what I am trying to do is query my Minecraft server. Check if a player is online by the text form on button click, and if not, deliver a message that says the player is not online, otherwise, keep the person logged in as they browse the site (dunno how to do this either...)
The external query file is:

```
<?php
class MinecraftQueryException extends Exception
{
// Exception thrown by MinecraftQuery class
}

class MinecraftQuery
{
/*
 * Class written by xPaw
 *
 * Website: http://xpaw.ru
 * GitHub: https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query
 */

const STATISTIC = 0x00;
const HANDSHAKE = 0x09;

private $Socket;
private $Players;
private $Info;

public function Connect( $Ip, $Port = 25565, $Timeout = 3 )
{
    if( !is_int( $Timeout ) || $Timeout < 0 )
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException( 'Timeout must be an integer.' );
    }

    $this->Socket = @FSockOpen( 'udp://' . $Ip, (int)$Port, $ErrNo, $ErrStr, $Timeout );

    if( $ErrNo || $this->Socket === false )
    {
        throw new MinecraftQueryException( 'Could not create socket: ' . $ErrStr );
    }

    Stream_Set_Timeout( $this->Socket, $Timeout );
    Stream_Set_Blocking( $this->Socket, true );

    try
    {
        $Challenge = $this->GetChallenge( );

        $this->GetStatus( $Challenge );
    }
    // We catch this because we want to close the socket, not very elegant
    catch( MinecraftQueryException $e )
    {
        FClose( $this->Socket );

        throw new MinecraftQueryException( $e->getMessage( ) );
    }

    FClose( $this->Socket );
}

public function GetInfo( )
{
    return isset( $this->Info ) ? $this->Info : false;
}

public function GetPlayers( )
{
    return isset( $this->Players ) ? $this->Players : false;
}

private function GetChallenge( )
{
    $Data = $this->WriteData( self :: HANDSHAKE );

    if( $Data === false )
    {
        throw new MinecraftQueryException( 'Offline' );
    }

    return Pack( 'N', $Data );
}

private function GetStatus( $Challenge )
{
    $Data = $this->WriteData( self :: STATISTIC, $Challenge . Pack( 'c*', 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 ) );

    if( !$Data )
    {
        throw new MinecraftQueryException( 'Failed to receive status.' );
    }

    $Last = '';
    $Info = Array( );

    $Data    = SubStr( $Data, 11 ); // splitnum + 2 int
    $Data    = Explode( "\x00\x00\x01player_\x00\x00", $Data );

    if( Count( $Data ) !== 2 )
    {
        throw new MinecraftQueryException( 'Failed to parse server\'s response.' );
    }

    $Players = SubStr( $Data[ 1 ], 0, -2 );
    $Data    = Explode( "\x00", $Data[ 0 ] );

    // Array with known keys in order to validate the result
    // It can happen that server sends custom strings containing bad things (who can know!)
    $Keys = Array(
        'hostname'   => 'HostName',
        'gametype'   => 'GameType',
        'version'    => 'Version',
        'plugins'    => 'Plugins',
        'map'        => 'Map',
        'numplayers' => 'Players',
        'maxplayers' => 'MaxPlayers',
        'hostport'   => 'HostPort',
        'hostip'     => 'HostIp'
    );

    foreach( $Data as $Key => $Value )
    {
        if( ~$Key & 1 )
        {
            if( !Array_Key_Exists( $Value, $Keys ) )
            {
                $Last = false;
                continue;
            }

            $Last = $Keys[ $Value ];
            $Info[ $Last ] = '';
        }
        else if( $Last != false )
        {
            $Info[ $Last ] = $Value;
        }
    }

    // Ints
    $Info[ 'Players' ]    = IntVal( $Info[ 'Players' ] );
    $Info[ 'MaxPlayers' ] = IntVal( $Info[ 'MaxPlayers' ] );
    $Info[ 'HostPort' ]   = IntVal( $Info[ 'HostPort' ] );

    // Parse "plugins", if any
    if( $Info[ 'Plugins' ] )
    {
        $Data = Explode( ": ", $Info[ 'Plugins' ], 2 );

        $Info[ 'RawPlugins' ] = $Info[ 'Plugins' ];
        $Info[ 'Software' ]   = $Data[ 0 ];

        if( Count( $Data ) == 2 )
        {
            $Info[ 'Plugins' ] = Explode( "; ", $Data[ 1 ] );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $Info[ 'Software' ] = 'Vanilla';
    }

    $this->Info = $Info;

    if( $Players )
    {
        $this->Players = Explode( "\x00", $Players );
    }
}

private function WriteData( $Command, $Append = "" )
{
    $Command = Pack( 'c*', 0xFE, 0xFD, $Command, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 ) . $Append;
    $Length  = StrLen( $Command );

    if( $Length !== FWrite( $this->Socket, $Command, $Length ) )
    {
        throw new MinecraftQueryException( "Failed to write on socket." );
    }

    $Data = FRead( $this->Socket, 2048 );

    if( $Data === false )
    {
        throw new MinecraftQueryException( "Failed to read from socket." );
    }

    if( StrLen( $Data ) < 5 || $Data[ 0 ] != $Command[ 2 ] )
    {
        return false;
    }

    return SubStr( $Data, 5 );
}
}
```

I would like to solve this in any way that I can. Thanks in advance and ask any questions you need :D.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a form pointing to the same URL to accomplish that.

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" />
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

When the form is sent, you can access your input content by accessing `$_POST['username']`

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    // your code here
    echo 'Username: ' . $_POST['username'];
}
```

Comment: How do you access test if any string of the query data matches the submitted content? Also, my php has an error apparently.

Comment: Yeah, why did you put that PHP code inside a string? (`$string = '<?php if( ( $Players = $Query->GetPlayers( ) ) !== false ): ?>`)

Comment: I don't know. Is there a complete way to solve this issue without roundabouts?

Comment: Well, a PHP code inside a string won't do anything, it will be just some code represented as text. Read more about the if and foreach statements in the PHP website so you can learn more about how you can accomplish what you are trying to do. Read about var_dump also, it's a function that shows what content a variable holds, it will be very useful for debugging.

Comment: GRAVEDIGGING! Seriously though, java is easier to code in.